# How to run a command (that's meant for parent shell) from a shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

What connects an instance of an interpreter to a specific session? For example, what is specific to a terminal instance that makes a command like `jobs` only show jobs in that very instance of interpreter? (like when you open another terminal?) How can I get `jobs` command in a shell script to show all of the jobs in its parent shell?

Comment: You'll want to read about subshells, inheritance, and the `source` command (AKA `.`).

Comment: Thank you so much , i'll study that . i'm a newbie, but i'm very excited to learn.  i'll take any help i can get.

Comment: Actually, after some research, subshells and inheritance have more to do with variables and functions. Still worth reading about, but not really relevant.

Answer (score 2):

> what makes a command like `jobs` only show jobs in that very instance of interpreter?

`jobs` shows the jobs the shell (that particular shell process) has started. The shell  keeps track of what commands it started, gives then numbers (*job ids*), and knows their status since parent processes are notified when their child processes exit.

The shell has no knowledge of processes started by other shell instances, or other programs.

> How can I get `jobs` command in a shell script to show all of the jobs in its parent shell?

You don't.

Of course you could browse the data in `/proc` or the output of `ps` to find the child processes of the parent, but there's no direct way for  processes don't know about their siblings. Even less about their relation to each other, e.g. which ones are part of a same pipeline.

Comment: Let's also emphasize that `jobs` is a shell builtin to be able to do this, not an external command.